Adding Web API Calls to Blazor Web App (Template) Redirects to Login with [Authorize] controllers
I have a .Net WASM project that I am migrating to .Net 8 from .Net6. I want to take advantage of some of the advanced render modes.
I used the template in VS2022 with Individual accounts, With 'Auto (Server and WebAssemby) and per page/component as the interactivity location. (I included the sample pages).
I have been struggling so have reduced my app to some simple elements to aid testing. The login etc are all working fine with the template pages. But once 'logged in' I need to get the user details and do other things. Presently via webAPI using WebAssembly (I will move to combined rendering with Interfaces later).
When not logged in, the [Authorize]'d controllers server side is sending back the login page when not logged in (instead of 401 unauthorized). I think this is some set up in the template, but have not been able to figure out a work around. When logged in all is fine.
I have two simple controllers: TestController (not authorized) and ValuesController (authorized),
This is my backend 'Program.cs:
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
            .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
            .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

        builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
            .AddIdentityCookies();

        var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<RGDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        //builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RGDbContext>()
        //    .AddSignInManager()
        //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RGDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        //builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
        //{
        //    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7274")
        //});

        string baseURI = builder.Configuration["applicationUrl"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseURI))
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURI)
            });

            // Add a CORS policy for the client
            // Add .AllowCredentials() for apps that use an Identity Provider for authn/z
            builder.Services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    policy => policy.WithOrigins(baseURI,
                    baseURI)
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()));

        }

        builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationEvents>(options =>
        {
            options.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"))
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
                context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        });


        //builder.Services.AddControllers(); // For web Api

        // The options are to stop it enforcing null value checking in json packets to and from the server.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(
            options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true
            );


        builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        #region  ****My services and configs****

         ... stuff

        #endregion  ***********************************

        ////////////APP Section
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Activate the CORS policy
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAntiforgery();

        app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
            .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
            .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
            .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(RaffleGames.Client._Imports).Assembly);

        // Add additional endpoints required by the Identity /Account Razor components.
        app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();

        app.MapControllers();
            
        app.Run();

This is the code for the Client program.cs:
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

    builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
    builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();

    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
    });

    builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();

This is the Test Controller:
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class TestController : ControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return Ok("Yes");
            }
        }

This is the Values Controller:
        [Authorize]
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                return Ok("Yes");
            }
        }

As you can see, can't really be any simpler as far as the controllers go.
I have tried a few things I found from here and MS pages but so far to no avail.
I tried adding this to the server side program.cs:
     builder.Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationEvents>(options =>
 {
      options.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
      {
         if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"))
         {
             context.Response.Clear();
             context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
             return Task.FromResult(0);
         }
         context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
     };
});

I also tried the solution to this question:
ASP.Net / ASP.NET Core Web API unauthorized requests returns 302 redirect response instead of 401
This looks like something to do with the way the user accounts in the template are set up.

Do you set a breakpoint at if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api")) ? If it excute it ?

I have actually solved this now.. but its a bit of a cludge (I feel), so I wanted to wait a day or two to see  if someone came out with a technically elegant solution. i.e not having to intercept the cookie autt events...
